# How to send user.id with :user in params even though user.name is what is in the form drop down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Currently, I have an action in my customers controller generating an array of names, `@username_array`, of all objects of class User with which to populate a drop down menu in a form that creates a new object of class Customer. The form element looks like this right now:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, @username_array %>
```

What I'd really like is for the `id` of the user to be sent into params[:customer][:user_id] instead of the `name` of that user that is chosen in the drop down. So in my `create` action in my customers controller I have the following code:

```
@customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
@user = User.find_by_name(params[:customer][:user_id]) # where :user_id is actually currently the name selected from the drop down
@customer.user_id = @user.id
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **@username_array** to include both the name and the id of the user:

Instead of:

```
["Bob","Sally","Dave"]
```

Make it:

```
[["Bob", 1],["Sally",2],["Dave",3]]
```

This could be accomplished by something like this:

```
@username_array = User.all.map {|user| [user.name, user.id]}
```

Then, f.select will display the name in the dropdown, but the actual value passed in through params[:customer][:user_id] will be the id of the user, which is what you want. With this in place, the following is all you need in the controller action code:

```
@customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
```

You won't have to look up the user by name, the params hash will already have the correct id value.

Note that instead of making @username_array an instance variable you could just create a utility method in the helper for this controller, or the application helper:

```
def user_select
  User.all.map {|user| [user.name, user.id]}
end
```

Then, in your view:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, user_select %>
```

If you put this in your application helper, you can use it everywhere and only have the code in one place (DRY).

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
@user = User.find_by_name(params[:customer][:user_id])
@user.customers.new(params[:customer])
```

or

```
@user = User.find_by_name(params[:customer][:user_id])
@customer = @user.customers.create(params[:customer])
```

but to do that you must have the relation (has_many, belongs_to,...)

or

```
Customer.new(params[:customer], :user_id => params[:customer][:user_id])
```

or

```
f.collection_select :user_id, @username_array, :id, :name
```